# Apache PIG: Processing time taken by different operators in a PIG script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, operator-keyword

I had a question related to figuring out the times taken by the various operators in a PIG script. For example, my script used the below operators:

LOAD..
FOREACH..GENERATE..
GROUP BY...
FOREACH..GENERATE..
JOIN...
UNION...

Now, when the script is run, it runs a series of 1 or more MapReduce jobs. Now, if i want to tune the performance of my script, i would like to know which operator has taken a lot of time. Is there a way for me to check how long did each operator take to run?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi - not sure why the downgrade on the question? Just need to know so i don't repeat the same in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably u can look into Oreilly's 'programming Pig' to get to know which function goes for a reduce stage and which only requires a map phase. There are different kinds of join and you will get to know how many MR phases does each join requires. That will help you in improving your performance. And by the way your log will also give you some hint.

```
Job Stats (time in seconds):
JobId   Maps    Reduces MaxMapTime  MinMapTime  AvgMapTime  MedianMapTime   MaxReduceTime   MinReduceTime   AvgReduceTime   MedianReducetime    Alias   Feature Outputs
job_201510052259_0002   1   0   4   4   4   4   0   0   0   0   A,B **MAP_ONLY**    hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/temp585169456/tmp-938748827,
```

Comment: Thanks Vignesh. I had seen the Job_Stats output, but it provides aggregated statistics like Max, Min or Avg. I was trying to find more information like what Jie Li has referred to in his blog here.

Comment: Thanks Vignesh. I had seen the Job_Stats output, but it provides aggregated statistics like Max, Min or Avg. I was trying to find more information like what Jie Li has referred to in his blog here - https://hortonworks.com/blog/pig-performance-and-optimization-analysis/. Jie has talked about ‘type conversion’ and how he figured that it took a lot of time in a query he was testing. So, i was trying to find out if there is a tool/output on those lines.

Comment: Try loading a huge dataset one with defining a schema with its individual types for each column and other without types. You will see the difference. Because when you don't specify the schema pig assumes everything as bytearray and it proceeds,later if it changes it depending on the function. So what pig does with lazy type conversion is that it delays the casting until it is necessary. So pig will not spend much time in loading your data by doing all the type conversion if you specify a type.